# How to get text from Web page in macOS via Swift?

Tags: html, swift, macos, safari, webkit

How to get a string of text like this:

```
Simple Text Example...
```

from macOS' Safari page via Swift 4?

```
@IBOutlet weak var label: NSTextField!
@IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let string = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/101"
    let url = NSURL(string: string)
    let request = URLRequest(url: url! as URL)
    self.webView.load(request as URLRequest)

    //this doesn't work
    label.stringValue = webView.webFrame.frameElement.innerText
}
```

Here is HTML structure:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
    <body>
      Simple Text Example...
    </body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE:**

I've tried the following method but it has Void return...

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.innerText") { (result, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print(result)
    }
}
```

Comment: remove the error check because error is not nil when and only when the JS failed evaluating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**for iOS, in the webview's delegate method**

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {  
    var string = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.body.textContent")
    print(string)
}
```

**for macOS, in the webview's navigation delegate:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    webview.nagivationDelegate = self
    ...
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.textContent") { (string, error) in
            print(string)
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, there's no there's no `.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript()` method in macOS. Only `.evaluateJavaScript()` with Void return...

Comment: my apologies. I thought it was in iOS. So you can do similar thing on macOS. See my updated answer, plz

Comment: Works fine! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

**You have to check outerhtml and innerhtml, textContent and many more tag like that:**

```
if let htmlOuter = self.webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.body.outerHTML"){
}
```

> Or

```
if let htmlInner = self.webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.body.innerHTML"){

}
```

> Or

```
if let content = self.webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.body. textContent"){

}
```